# Bash -- reversing MD5 output in a text file & sorting

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file1.txt with a list of MD5sums and corresponding filenames.

```
edad74614d6d3fa2252c3d74ff037ac7  wp-blog-header.php
de4edc0df80ba147ebcc26f9e0a8b96f  wp-config.php
68070de41736e57f8757648a80b9cbbb  wp-admin/upgrade-functions.php
29b6a5c82153f1371e1188ffa7b47619  wp-admin/error_log
55373449cc2320c57803f1f5b52b9ce9  wp-admin/edit.php
```

How do I dump this to a file2.txt with lines starting with the filenames instead of the hash and sort alphabetically like such:

```
wp-blog-header.php  edad74614d6d3fa2252c3d74ff037ac7
wp-config.php  de4edc0df80ba147ebcc26f9e0a8b96f
wp-admin/edit.php  55373449cc2320c57803f1f5b52b9ce9
wp-admin/error_log  29b6a5c82153f1371e1188ffa7b47619
wp-admin/upgrade-functions.php  68070de41736e57f8757648a80b9cbbb
```

Thank you so, so much!

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. So you want to sort only on filenames and not on the whole path? Whole path is easier. Do the paths contain spaces? Is something like `wp-admin/foo bar.php` possible?

Comment: The reason of the sorting is so that I can then compare the file2.txt with a file3.txt for non-matching lines for "file change detection". I figure this is more efficient with alphabetical sorting. It's better to have space tolerable code just in case.

Comment: More efficient than alphabetical sorting? But it looks like you want the filenames alphabetically sorted (or lexicographically sorted, rather)

Comment: I guess it's better you would post the activity you were going to do compare for _file change_ with X-->Y way instead of going into [X-->X1-->Y](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004468/bash-reversing-md5-output-in-a-text-file-sorting#comment1625257_1004468) way.

Comment: Do you have just access to the list of md5 and filenames? If you have access to the files you could just use specialized tools like `meld`, `diff` or `rsync` for whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to sort a text file based on specific columns you don't need to change the column order if you use the `-k` option of GNU `sort`. To only sort based on the 2nd and subsequent (white-space delimited) columns use:

```
sort -k 2
```

Additionally I advise you to use the `C` or `POSIX` collation locale to compare and sort path names or you may receive unexpected results due to case-insensitivity or special characters:

```
LC_COLLATE=POSIX sort ...
```

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk '{ print $2, $1 }' < file | sort > file2
```

This will take the data from the file called 'file', swap the two fields and sort them into file 'file2'

Answer (score 0):

From comment section I believe what you are looking for is "change tracking", instead of "comparison of MD5 strings".

Based on @Colin lan King's answer. I have developed this bash script which realizes this operation:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Difference of all files within /etc
find_etc () {
    find /etc -type f -exec sh -c "md5sum {} | sort -bd" {} \;
}

md5_files="$(find_etc)"

date=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
echo "$md5_files">/acme_tools/ids/inventory.$date.txt

echo -e "\nGenerating /acme_tools/ids/inventory.<yyyymmdd_hhmmss>.txt"
ls /acme_tools/ids/ | grep inventory.$date.txt

echo -e "\nMD5 hash of each text file:"
for txt in /acme_tools/ids/*.txt; do md5sum $txt; done | awk '{print $2, $1}' | sort -bn

echo ""
```

**This script does:**

1. Generate MD5 strings for all files under /etc, the difference of a
   series of generated text files will be used for tracking
2. Generate a date string in YYYYmmdd_hhmmss for numeric sorting

   - (you can use other datetime format, but that would make sorting command more complicated)
3. Since bash usually highlight outputs from `grep`, we use that to denote the text-file we've just generated
4. Then, give bash a for-loop that does `md5sum` for each text file generated over time
5. Immediately pipe the result from loop to `awk` and reverse it
6. Finally pipe the result from `awk` to `sort` with `-b` to ignore blanks, `-n` to sort with number

**You get:**

```
Generating /acme_tools/ids/inventory.<yyyymmdd_hhmmss>.txt
inventory.20230206_033543.txt

MD5 hash of each text file:
/acme_tools/ids/inventory.20230206_033102.txt 2fac123738b76a2ba96a3f204a294093
/acme_tools/ids/inventory.20230206_033137.txt 2fac123738b76a2ba96a3f204a294093
/acme_tools/ids/inventory.20230206_033527.txt 46f7c817b3980bcd4efe57dc1a3b10ce
/acme_tools/ids/inventory.20230206_033543.txt 46f7c817b3980bcd4efe57dc1a3b10ce
```

We can see the **change of MD5 hash strings over time**.